# Can I run these games on my system?

Tags: 13.04, ati, games

I have an Ubuntu PC with these specs:  [HP G62-378CA](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c02618765) .

I would like to know if I would be able to run Team fortress 2 and/or Counter Strike Source.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try running it and see if it works?

Comment: People who down voted and/or is attempting to close this question as "Not constructive" should first read this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6833/dont-vote-to-close-if-its-just-a-bad-question-fix-it-or-vote-it-down Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

The specs on the page you refer to seem promising. Of those I would only point to an issue if your **ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250 Graphics** Is less than 512MB (The specs reads: ***Up to 1917MB*** but it doesn't mean that it already has that amount of MB).

Your microprocessor is good enough to have a good experience when playing but you may expect some lag and choppy graphics, especially on Team Fortress 2.

Counter Strike will run smoother.

Just make sure that your GPU is good for 512MB min and install. As I say, you will be able to run it, but the results will depend on your Microprocessor's speed and GPU physical memory.

Good luck!

Comment: will it run if i did not install the ati drivers and i kept the out of the box drivers

Comment: I don't think so. Specially TF2, it will drop an error on your GPU and won't run. You'll need the latest drivers in order to have a better graphical experience.

Comment: Microprocessor?

Comment: I have no Clue to be truthful but so far some things like GTA3 On wine works fine im talking about source i guess il try it myself and chekc if it works

Comment: I don't think you can change your microprocessor's speed but if you can change the microprocessor for a faster one, you'll experience a smoother graphics and less choppy gaming. In example: We are using two Core2Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz, the first with 4GB and the other with 8GB RAM and we are yet experiencing some lag and choppy graphics in certain cases. We can live with that, but the problem may be bigger, specially if we play online and there are too many players connected. And when I say "too many players" I am talking about 16 total players (players and/or bots included).

Answer (score 0):

You have more than enough CPU and RAM for this games and looking at your 
[ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250 Specs](http://www.notebookcheck.net/ATI-Radeon-HD-4250.29664.0.html), I can see it supports DirectX 10.1 and Shader 4.0. With this in mind and knowing that the hardware is far superior to the recommended requirements I can give you 2 alternatives:

If you are going to use Wine with the proprietary ATI drivers then yes, they will work and run perfectly with or without Steam. Your hardware is way above the one this games need as seen here:

- [Team Fortress 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/440/)
- [Counter-Strike Source](http://store.steampowered.com/app/240)

If you are going to use Steam (Without Wine) it is still needed for you to install the Proprietary drivers. The open source ones are not yet to the level of performance of the Proprietary ones. For the drivers please see [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

In both cases you need:

- Install the Proprietary Drivers if you wish to have the best performance while playing the games.
- In the case of Team Fortress 2, even though the steam app link does not mention Linux of the hardware requirements [it is supported](http://www.teamfortress.com/linux/).
- Your only problem might be some OpenGL Texture Compressions missing (Even after installing the Proprietary Drivers). For this simply do the following on the terminal:

  sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0

With all of this in mind you should be more than fine running those games on Ubuntu (Specially via Steam).